# Error plugin WindowBuilder eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

Hola buenas acabo de instalar el **WindowBuilder**, pero me salta el siguiente error.

> Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 1.8 Java
> compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load
> classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project,
> or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.

¿A qué se debe?

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo en concreto a tu pregunta, se debe a que la versión del plugin no soporta aún la versión que le marcaste, tal vez deberías de buscar actualizaciones o en su defecto, según [esta pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408029/incompatible-java-versions-for-windowbuilder) bajar el compilance level al primer número que te indique en el mensaje de error, esto se hace mediante:

1. Selecciona el nondo del proyecto en el explorador de
   proyecto(Project Explorer), dale lick derecho y selecciona
   propiedades.
2. Selecciona Java Compiler de la columna de la izquierda.
3. Desmarca la casilla Use Compliance from execution environment...
4. Selecciona el primer numero de versión que te indique de la lista
   desplegable donde dice Compiler compliance level.
5. Dale Click en Apply y luego en Close para aplicar y cerrar.

[image: opción Java Compiler en la ventana de propiedades del eclipse IDE]

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @CarlosPerandelBrio te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y si consideras que mi respuesta te ayudó una flecha arriba sería de mucha ayuda, si resolvió tu problema la palomita verde existe para eso. Saludos.